# Python PIllow - edit existing ImageTk objects

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Creating objects using ImageTk objects do no create copies, only keep reference to that object, which means using the same picture 100 times and editing it once would change all of the pictures. I need exactly that. Here is what I tried:

```
from  tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.image = Image.open("engflag.png")
        self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.button = Button(self, command = self.test)
        self.button.grid()
    def test(self):
        print(self.tkimage)
        self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        print(self.tkimage)


x = App()
x.mainloop()
```

In the first print statement the self.tkimage has the reference for the first object and prints "pyimage1". In the next line a new object gets created from the already loaded self.image and the self.tkimage now has the reference to the second object and the next print statement prints "pyimage2".

Is it possible to create a new image object and replace it with the old one  or edit the first one directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageTk.paste()` to replace `Image` in `ImageTk`

```
self.image2 = Image.open(...)

self.tkimage.past(self.image2)
```

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm

Comment: This is not good. When changing from bigger to smaller the original size remains while the smaller image gets pasted on top ruining the whole thing.

Comment: I checked with the same size image :) Then probably there is no solution - you have to create new `ImageTk`

Comment: Do you happen to know how do I get rid of the "old" ones ? I dont want to flood the memory with useless data.

Comment: Python use `GC` (`Garbage Collector`) and it should do it automatically but you can try `del self.tkimage`